# How can I find all intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[d]{a}\right)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $a$ be a positive rational number, $n$ be a natural number, and $K$ be extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\sqrt[n]{a}$.

I guess that intermediate field $E$ between $K$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with  $\left[E:\mathbb{Q}\right]=d$($d\mid n$) is unique as $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[d]{a}\right)$. But I can't prove this guess. If $\mathbb{Q}$ has a root of unity $\zeta_{n}$, It should be so easy. But It doesn't. How can I prove that without $\zeta_{n}$?

And is there a formula computing $\text{Gal}\left(x^{n}-a\right)$?

Comment: I've posted a [question on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208850/subfields-of-mathbbq-bigl-sqrtna-bigr-for-a0) asking whether there's an elementary proof of this theorem.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348621/radical-extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be a surprisingly difficult question, but it's true that the intermediate fields are precisely those of the form $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[d]{a}\bigr)$ for $d$ a divisor of $n$.

More generally, if $a_1,\ldots,a_t$ are positive rational numbers and $n_1,\ldots,n_t$ are natural numbers, then every field intermediate between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[n_1]{a_1},\ldots,\sqrt[n_t]{a_t}\bigr)$ is generated by monomials in the roots $\sqrt[n_i]{a_i}$.

You can find this result proven immediately after Theorem 1.6 in [Greither, Cornelius, and David K. Harrison. "A Galois correspondence for radical extensions of fields." *Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* 43.3 (1986): 257-270.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404986900678)  In general, proving results like this apparently involves something called "cogalois theory", which involves a "cogalois correspondence" between intermediate fields of a "cogalois extension" and subgroups of the "cogalois group".  The linked paper from 1986 seems to have been the beginning of this subject, but since then [entire books have been written about it](https://books.google.com/books?id=8gv-HubNqtQC).

The splitting field of $x^n - a$ is $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta\bigr)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity.  The Galois group of $x^n - a$ is difficult to analyze in general.  It fits into a short exact sequence
$$
\mathrm{Gal}\bigl(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta)\,\bigr/\,\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\bigr) \;\longrightarrow\; \mathrm{Gal}\bigl(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta)\,\bigr/\,\mathbb{Q}\bigr) \;\longrightarrow\; \mathrm{Gal}\bigl(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\,\bigr/\,\mathbb{Q}\bigr)
$$
where:

- $\mathrm{Gal}\bigl(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\,\bigr/\,\mathbb{Q}\bigr) \,\cong\, (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, the multiplicative group of units modulo $n$.
- $\mathrm{Gal}\bigl(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a},\zeta)\,\bigr/\,\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\bigr) \,\cong\, \mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$, where $r$ is the smallest positive integer for which $\bigl(\sqrt[n]{a}\bigr)^r$ lies in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

Note that $r$ in general may be a divisor of $n$.  For example, even though $x^8-2$ is irreducible over the rationals, the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(e^{i\pi/4}\bigr)$ contains $\sqrt{2}$; then $x^8-2$ factors into $(x^4-\sqrt{2})(x^4-\sqrt{2})$ over this field, so in this case $r=4$.  According to the above sequence, the Galois group is some extension of $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ by $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and it turns out to be the dihedral group of order 16.

In the case where $r=n$, the sequence splits and the Galois group is isomorphic to the semidirect product $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ with the obvious action.  It's easy to check in this case that all the intermediate fields are generated by powers of $\sqrt[n]{a}$.

For $r<n$, we get some extension of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ by $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$, but there doesn't seem to be any simple general description of this extension.  Again, I am not an expert in Galois theory, and I know virtually nothing about cogalois theory, so it's possible that a nice description does exist somewhere in the literature.

Comment: Thank you for helpful answer. I got some idea about the first question, "Find all intermediate field" from your answer. Let me explain the idea.
Let $L$ be a spilitting field of $x^{n}-a$. You make me know Galois group $G:=\text{Gal}\left(x^{n}-a\right)$ is some composition of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\left(\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$. And already I know  $\text{Gal}\left(L/K\right)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, "intuitively" $\text{Gal}\left(L/E\right)$ is dealt with subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ which is another composition part of $G$. And it is cyclic. So, if $\left[K:E\right]$ is decided, $\text{Gal}\left(L/E\right)$ is also uniquely.
But I can't prove that "$\text{Gal}\left(L/E\right)$ is dealt with subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$". Can you help more about this?

Comment: @jawlang I'm not sure what more you're hoping for.  The linked paper has a proof of the result, but it's fairly complicated.  The Galois group is certainly not cyclic in general.

Comment: I agree that my question is complicated. What I mean is like this. Let's think Galois correspodence about $L/K/E$. It is $G=\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}\diamond\left(\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}\right)>H>\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}\diamond 1>1
 $.(I used symbol $\diamond$ for some composition between $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ and $\left(\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}\right)$. As you refered, we don't know shape of $\diamond$.)

Comment: From this relation, I guessed $H=\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}\diamond A$ for some $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}>A>1$. Is this assumption right? If it is, how can I prove it?

Comment: @jawlang It doesn't make sense to talk about $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times \diamond 1$ when $G$ isn't a split extension.  Your argument will work in the $n=r$ case, where $G$ is just a semidirect product, but it won't work in general.